# Fastest way to create animated gifs from mp4

Tags: linux, image-processing, ffmpeg, imagemagick, animated-gif

I have to batch process a very high number(200,000+) of short mp4s(less then 10s) into animated gifs.  I think I have tried every possible command line way of doing it, but it still takes too long to produce quality gifs.  Currently I use ffmpeg to unpack image(jpg) frames, and image magick convert to assemble them.  It produces high quality gifs, but takes too long and uses too much memory and CPU, even with tweaking with the -limit memory and map limits.

I have also tried creating animated gifs directly using ffmpeg, but the quality is terrible at best.  Also, I have tried using gifsicle, which does seem fast, but it only takes gifs as inputs, and using ffmpeg to generate them produces poor quality gifs.

Does anyone have some command line recipes for fast high quality gif creation?

Comment: I've had a tiny bit of exposure to some of these tools.  Is it possible to pass output via pipes to the various stages. That can dramatically improve processing times (sometimes!). Also, in project management studies, you'll learn that there is almost always a trade off between time, resources and quality. ;-/ . Good luck.

Comment: Also see [ffmpeg converts .flv video to .gif with awful quality](http://superuser.com/a/556031/110524).

Answer (score 18):

For first you should create a set of jpg images with maximum quality using `mplayer` and `jpeg` option sets to 100 (jpeg:quality=100).

```
mplayer -ao null -ss 0:00:00 -endpos 10 mts.flv -vo jpeg:outdir=jpeg_dir:quality=100
```

Next, you need to convert generated jpgs to gifs using `convert`, just type:

```
for i in ./jpeg_dir/*.jpg; do convert "$i" "${i%.jpg}.gif"; done
```

And finally using `gifsicle` create animated gif:

```
gifsicle --delay=10 --loop ./jpeg_dir/*.gif > anim.gif
```

Also, you can use optimization level flag `--optimize=03`. It can be helpful to reduce file size:

```
gifsicle --delay=10 --optimize=03 --loop *.gif > anim.gif
```

Additionally, you can manipulate with number of colors `--colors num` of current palette 
and `--color-method method` to determine most appropriate palette.

As for me most appropriate method is `median-cut`

```
median-cut is the median cut algorithm described by Heckbert
```

Also, I try to manipulate with described flags and found most useful options to achieve
better quality of generated gif-image:

```
gifsicle --delay=3 --optimize=03 --color-method median-cut --loop *.gif > anim.gif
```

Be accurate with `--delay=NUM` to correspond animation speed . This param depends on FPS of original video.

Comment: As mentioned in my original comment, I have tried that route. The individual gifs ffmpeg produces are of very low quality.  These lead to low quality animated gifs in the end.

Comment: I've updated my answer by adding a couple additional steps to get set of images with more high quality than can provide ffmpeg:
mplayer -ao null -ss 0:00:00 -endpos 10 video.flv -vo jpeg:outdir=jpeg_dir; and

for i in *.jpg; do convert "$i" "${i%.jpg}.gif"; done

Answer (score 0):

It could improve passing from uncompressed images, like .ppm, for example with mplayer the command line would be:

```
mplayer -benchmark -noframedrop -nosound -vf format=rgb24 -vo pnm *.avi -osdlevel 0
```

These will save the jpg compress/uncompress cycle.

It would also help working with a Solid State Drive.

Answer (score 0):

Use "animate" program from imagemagick package after splitting video to images. Like this
animate ./*.jpg. 
Then just save opened merged in ImageMagick program images as gif. But it may be large/ Then nеed to optimize and resize(better to do it with mplayer first scale=240:180).